# Why must backslashes in string literals be escaped in C++?

Tags: php, c++, escaping, tcl

I want to declare the same regex pattern for both languages. For TCL I do this

```
set pattern "\d\s\S"
```

but for C++ I have to do this for the same pattern

```
boost::regex pattern("\\d\\s\\S");
```

otherwise C++ compiler will tell us the following:

```
warning C4129: 'd' : unrecognized character escape sequence
```

so why TCL don't try to find \d \s \S escape symbols and just ignores `\`-s but C++ tries and sucks?

P.S. PHP works as TCL as I remeber.

Comment: This is programming language specific. Some language like `C++, C, Java` need you to double escape. While some other like - `Perl, PHP,` don't need it.

Comment: If you're using a C++11-capable compiler you can use the new raw string literals. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#New_string_literals

Comment: This question has nothing to do with PHP or TCL, it's squarely about C++. Just because it mentions PHP and TCL doesn't mean it should appear in those categories, because PHP or TCL experts can't answer this question.

Comment: I don't think so. Even more I think a TCL or PHP expert can briliantly know why when you do `set a "\dumb"` then it is being interpreted as `dumb`. Which may be enough to me to understand why in C++ it is not so.

Comment: @Narek - The C++ designers (or C actually) chose to treat `"\dumb"` and `"\thumb"` the same, because they thought it would be confusing otherwise.

Comment: Yes, maybe this is the reason!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just how C++ and PHP differ; in PHP, the character following a backslash is matched against a small set of special characters (I believe `"rnvtx"`). If the match fails it will just continue without altering the meaning.

However, C++ expects the character to be in that small set (I think the set is bigger btw) but if the match fails you will see an error instead.

Answer (score 1):

C++ has the concept of [Character Escape Sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape). Escape sequences, which take the form `\c` (the 'c' being a character), are used to define certain special characters within string literals, so it follows that backslashes by themselves must also be escaped to denote that a special character isn't being implied.

Comment: PHP employs slightly [different rules](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) but the concept is similar. As for TCL, it has excellent Unicode support and can actually handle unprintable characters without resorting to escape sequences.

Comment: Tcl most certainly has [escape sequences](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M16), but it also has a syntax (with braces) for unsubstituted words. (The original question wouldn't have worked — in Tcl `"\d\s\S"` is the same as `dsS` — but `{\d\s\S}` would have been fine.)