# CreateDirectory function doesn't work

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to create a directory using CreateDirectory function. But it doesn't seem to work as i expect. What's wrong with my function?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    wchar_t *path = L"C:\\Users\TempFolder";
    CreateDirectory ( path , NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You did not check for errors. That's Win32 101. Please repeat after me, I promise to check for errors when I call Win32 API functions, I promise to check for errors when I call Win32 API functions, I promise to check for errors when I call Win32 API functions, .....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why must backslashes in string literals be escaped in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13986708/why-must-backslashes-in-string-literals-be-escaped-in-c)

Comment: I promise to check for errors when I call Win32 API functions, I promise to check for errors when I call Win32 API functions, I promise to check for errors when I call Win32 API functions, ;) :D thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a another backslash in there:

```
L"C:\\Users\\TempFolder"
```

And also make sure to run your program (.exe) as **admin**. You need to have admin privileges to create a folder in C:\Users.

Comment: Actually, just stop creating folders in that directory, it's not yours, the system owns it

Comment: Since this question is tagged [tag:c++], another option is to use raw [string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal): `LR"C:\windows\temp\TempFolder"`.

Comment: @IInspectable: raw string literals were added in C++11.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Correct. Raw string literals are supported by Visual Studio 2013 and above.

Comment: @IInspectable: My point is that not everyone uses VS2013+ or C++11 to begin with.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I'm pretty sure that if you are looking for a solution using C++98 or C++03 exclusively, you'd tag your question using the [tag:c++98] or [tag:c++03] tags, respectively. The [tag:c++] tag implies, that you do not care, which revision any given answer is using. Besides, I noted raw strings in a comment. There really is no reason to make that big of a fuss about it.

Comment: Also you need more warnings enabled (/wall) so that compiler can warn you of \T unrecognised char escape.