# why is Visual Studio is ridding my string of back-slashes

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio

I am pass the following string to a function as so

```
void func(string expr)
{ 
    regex pattern(expr);
}

func( "(\d{1,2}\.+\d{2})" )
```

however through the visual studio debugger I have found that the regex pattern being stored is actually `(d{1,2}.+d{2})` which is causing my regex to malfunction entirely. Why is this happening and how can I fix it.

Comment: Handy reading: [Escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)

Comment: C/C++ ["string literal"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/c-string-literals?view=vs-2019)  treat  the backslash ("\")  as ["escapes"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/escape-sequences?view=vs-2019).  SOLUTION: `func( "(\\d{1,2}\\.+\\d{2})" )`.  This will "escape" the "escape metacharacter".  Alternatively, in C#, you can use [@](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)

Comment: That link is for c#, not c++. @Pete-Becker

Comment: What about `R"[(\d{1,2}\.+\d{2})]"` ? Can that be done in C#? No. That link is not discoverable, because it does not have a C++ tag. And don't call people names.

Comment: @ScottHutchinson -- good point. Reopened. Apparently I can't vote to close it again, so someone else will have to do that with a more appropriate link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why must backslashes in string literals be escaped in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13986708/why-must-backslashes-in-string-literals-be-escaped-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are backslashes, which by default are escape characters. To treat them as literal characters...

Try this (in C++11). The R indicates a raw string, which takes the form `R "delimiter( raw_characters )delimiter"`, where delimiter can be any sequence of characters you like. In this case, I used just parentheses.

```
func( R"((\d{1,2}\.+\d{2}))" )
```

or this in any version:

```
func( "(\\d{1,2}\\.+\\d{2})" )
```